# How to check if apple device support GPU / neural engine in runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

I am working on coreML. Device which has neural engine(iPhone 13) able to process 5 images concurrently but device without neural engine(iPad 6th gen) unable to process multiple images at a time, able to process one image at a time. If I am trying to process multiple images at a time in a device which don't have neural engine support, app is crashing(Terminated due to memory issue).

Is there a way to process ML with multiple image concurrently without crash.

```
func execModelFromQueue(){
         for imageQueueObj in ImageQueueObjToAdd {
                    imageQueueObj.status = .InProgress
                    imageQueueObj.newStatus = true
                    self.runPrediciton(imageURL: imageQueueObj.imageURL, imageName: imageQueueObj.fileName) { [weak self] fileName, imageHailResult,  error in
                        guard let self = self else { return }
                        if let imageProccessed = self._imageQueue.filter({ $0.fileName == fileName }).first {
                            imageProccessed.status = .Done
                            imageProccessed.newStatus = false
                            imageProccessed.mlResult = imageHailResult
                            self.updateImageStatus(name: imageProccessed.fileName)
                        }
                        HailDamageHelper.storeHailDamage(jobId: self.jobId, fileName: fileName, imageMLHailResult: imageHailResult)
                        self.delegate?.didFinishFile(filename: fileName, imageMLHailResults: imageHailResult)
    }
  }
}
    
     private func runPrediciton(imageURL:URL, imageName:String, completion: @escaping (String, hailMLImageResult?, Error?) -> ()){
       for tile in imageTileSet!.tiles! {
                self.analyzeImage(fileName: imageName, tile: tile, tileSet: imageTileSet!) {[weak self]imageName, myTile, myTileSet, error, result in
                    guard error == nil, let self = self else { return }
                    myTile.mlOutput = result
                    myTile.proccessed = true
    }
  }
    
    private func analyzeImage(fileName: String, tile: hailMLImageTile, tileSet: hailMLImageTileSet, completion: @escaping (String, hailMLImageTile, hailMLImageTileSet, Error?, hail_v001Output?)->()){
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    do {
                        let startProcessDate = Date()
                        if let model = self.getHailModel() {
                            let input = try hail_v001Input(imageWith: tile.image!.cgImage!, iouThreshold: 0.6, confidenceThreshold: 0.4)
                            let output = try model.prediction(input: input)
                            let endProcessDate = Date()
    }
  }
```

Comment: I believe every iPhone and iPad ever made (even iPod touches) have had a GPU. What do you mean here by "support GPU?" Perhaps you're looking more for tools like https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/3191911-os_proc_available_memory?

Comment: It seems you are trying to solve XY problem here. Share the sample code and the error message it causes, provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and other debugging details as possible.

Comment: @PtitXav Please go through my question once again. I have attached code as well.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Error is : Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue.

Comment: @RameshKumar please revisit the code you shared. First - the inconsistent indentation makes it unreadable. Second - the code is missing square brackets to even compile. MRE has to be self-contained and should not require any changes from the readers to make it work.